# How much time is needed to add a child to a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I've got a Listview and an Adapter to this Listview. And a ArrayList which is bound(?) to that Adapter.

I'm adding an item to this Arraylist.
I call the notifyDataSetChanged() method.

I Directly after that I call

```
listview.getChildAt(myadapter.getCount()-1)
```

Now i get a NullpointerException.
In the Debugger I also see that mChildren of Listview is filled with null. 
Why is that so? Does it need more time?

Cu
JackZ

Answer (score 1):

It's because your listview adapter can have thousands of items, but listview has no more than ten to twenty direct children.

try to add this to your Activity.onCreate

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
a.add("0");
a.add("1");
final ListView lv = new ListView(this);
lv.setAdapter(a);
OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick cnt " + lv.getChildCount());
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick first " + lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick last " + lv.getLastVisiblePosition());
        a.add(Integer.toString(a.getCount()));
        lv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "run cnt " + lv.getChildCount());
                Log.d(TAG, "run first " + lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                Log.d(TAG, "run last " + lv.getLastVisiblePosition());
            }
        });
    }
};
lv.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
setContentView(lv);
```

and you will see how it works

Comment: I should have mentioned that it happens with the very first. And it also visible on screen

Comment: again, populate your adapter with hundrets items and for example in item click listener log lv.getChildCount(), you will see that although adapter.getCount() equals to hundrets items list view has only few direct children, so you cannot getChildAt(adapter.getCount() - 1)

Comment: Still that really isn't the problem! I also used ListView.getLastVisiblePosition() and it doesn't work...

Comment: because you can call getLastVisiblePosition() when list view is populated and items are visible, call it in some listener or (not sure) in listview.post(Runnable) after notifyDataSetChanged()